# Error when Joining table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am getting the error, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

All i want to do is use some columns from another table

```
SELECT  unitCode, studentID, s.studentFName 
FROM    Student As S Right outer Join       
      (SELECT unitCode, studentID, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN subStatus = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountYes, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN subStatus = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountNo
       FROM Assignment 
       GROUP BY unitCode, studentID) 
WHERE (CountNo > 0) AND (CountYes = 0) AND s.studentID = assignment.studentID
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing right bracket right at the end?

Comment: @BenClayton: Nope, there isn't :-)

Comment: @David: Why did you delete the statements from the question and tried to delete it from my answer?

Comment: @Daniel - Probably because it is homework (at least previous questions by the OP look very homeworky)

Comment: @David: Please stop destroying this question. If it is homework and you want to protect yourself, change the table and column names. I will change them in my answer then accordingly. However, I will not allow you to destroy this question by deleting the most important part.

Answer (score 3):

Your join is missing its `ON clause` and the subselect is missing the alias:

```
SELECT
    unitCode, studentID, s.studentFName 
FROM
    Student As S
    Right outer Join       
    (
        SELECT
            unitCode, studentID, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN subStatus = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountYes, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN subStatus = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountNo
        FROM
            Assignment 
        GROUP BY unitCode, studentID
    ) as assignment 
    on s.studentID = assignment.studentID 
WHERE 
    (CountNo > 0) AND (CountYes = 0)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Subselects must have an alias in SQL Server.

Change this:

```
OUTER JOIN (SELECT ...)
```

to this:

```
OUTER JOIN (SELECT ...) T1
```

Comment: And missing ON as Daniel mentioned...